# Looping through numerous Button variables

Tags: android, button, findviewbyid

I have 50 `Buttons` coded like this:

```
button_list.set(0,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button0));
button_list.set(1,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1));
button_list.set(2,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button2));
button_list.set(3,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button3));
button_list.set(4,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button4));
button_list.set(5,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button5));
button_list.set(6,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button6));
button_list.set(7,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button7));
button_list.set(8,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button8));
button_list.set(9,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button9));
button_list.set(10,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button10));
button_list.set(11,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button11));
button_list.set(12,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button12));
button_list.set(13,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button13));
button_list.set(14,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button14));
button_list.set(15,(Button) findViewById(R.id.button15));
.
.
.
```

How can I put this all in a loop?

When I run the below code I get `NullPointerExceptions`, I guess meaning the `Buttons` are not recognized when I attempt to use `findViewById`. Does anyone know what is wrong with the following code and how I can fix it?

```
Button[] bttn = new Button[50];

String ids[] = new String[50];
for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
{
   ids[i] = "button" + Integer.toString(i);
}

for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
{
   int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(ids[i], "id", "your.package.name");
   bttn[i] = (Button) findViewById(resID);
}


for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
{
   button_list.set(i, bttn[i]);
}
```

Comment: Did you replace `"your.package.name"` with the actual package name you are using as declared in the manifest? (Better yet, replace it with `getPackageName()` [or `getContext().getPackageName()` if this code is not in an `Activity`].)

Comment: Can you further explain what you want to achieve? I can not think about a situation, where I would need 50 independent buttons in a list. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a single loop

```
Button[] buttons = new Button[50];
for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    button[i] = (Button) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("button" + i, "id", getPackageName());
    buttonList.set(i, button[i]);   // if your list is already built
    //buttonList.add(button[1]);    // if you are building your list
}
```

I use `getPackageName()` as I assume you are in an Activity, if that is not the case you need to get a reference to the context and use `context.getPackageName();` This goes the same for the `getResources()` call as it also needs a reference to your context.

Comment: I get an error: The method getIdentifier(String, String, String) is undefined for the type Game (my class)

Comment: @user2456977 look at my update, may need to add `getResources()` or `getActivity().getResources()` (somehow reference your context and get the resources). Didn't realize you weren't in an activity.

Comment: I am in an activity but it only works when I add getResources. hm

Comment: @user2456977 cause I am a dummy, you have to get an explicit reference to your resources before you can get the identifier from it, I was just rushing through it :P Sorry for the error.